# Identify an async Void method through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, async-await

I'm analyzing a class through reflection and I want to check if a method is actually a `async void` method.

I have a `MethodInfo` object, and through it I can inspect the `ReturnType` property but that just says `Void`. Looking around I can't find a way to find to check if it's an async though.

Is there a way to see if a method is `async void`? Surely there must be?

Answer (score -1):

`async` is not part of the method signature, and as such you won't be able to determine whether the method is `async` or not from it's external API.

Comment: Presence or absence of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute` is reliable enough in that if someone is deliberately using it explicitly it's probably sensible to consider it equivalent to having `async` on it. Wanting to know this seems strange though.